# How do I create a dynamic callback functions in Python? (RPi 3 GPIO)

Tags: python, python-3.x, interrupt, raspberry-pi3, gpio

I'm programming an alarm system from the ground up for my project in python3-6, using an raspberry pi 3 and some alarm components (PIR, REED, etc)
To recieve alarms from the components I use the RPi.GPIO library which already has inbuilt Interrupt functionality.
Here is the code I wrote so far: **UPDATED 31.10.2017 15:44**

```
#Library Imports
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
time_stamp = time.time()

def PIRcallback(channel):
    print ('Alarm detected: ' + PIR.Name + '\nMotion!')
def REEDcallback(channel):
    print ('Alarm detected: ' + REED.Name + '\nDoor!')
def VIBRcallback(channel):
    print ('Alarm detected: ' + VIBR.Name + '\nWindow!')

class Alarm:
    def __init__(self, IO, pin, Name, cb_var):
        self.IO = IO
        self.pin = pin
        self.Name = Name
        self.callback_func = cb_var
        if (IO == 'input'):
            GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
        elif (IO == 'output'):
            GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.OUT)
        else:
            print ('Error: No input/output declared')
        self.addEvent('Up', 500)
    def addEvent(self, UpDown, btime):
        if (UpDown == 'Up'):
            UpDown = GPIO.RISING
        elif (UpDown == 'Down'):
            UpDown = GPIO.FALLING
        GPIO.add_event_detect(self.pin, UpDown, callback=self.cb, bouncetime=btime)
    def getPin(self):
        return self.pin
    def cb(self):
        global time_stamp
        time_now = time.time()
        print (time_now)
        if (time_now - time_stamp) >= 0.4:
            print (time_stamp)
            time_stamp = time_now
            self.callback_func()

#Testing Class Init     
REED = Alarm('input', 37, "REED", REEDcallback)
PIR = Alarm('input', 36, "PIR", PIRcallback)
VIBR = Alarm('input', 38, "VIBR", VIBRcallback)

try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.5)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print ("Terminating program...")
    time.sleep(1)
finally:
    GPIO.cleanup()
    print ("Cleaned GPIO!")
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: What do your individual callback functions need to do? i.e., what would the PIR callback do vs what would the REED callback do? How would they differ, and where would you expect to define that logic?

Comment: PIR callback should trigger a camera to activate, do snapshots, something in that area.
REED callback should only trigger an alarm, send an email or something like that.
Currently this would only differ in a different string being printed, since i don't have programmed said functionalities yet:
PIR Callback does print ("PIR Alarm")
REED callback does print ("REED Alarm")

I expected to define a dynamic callback function inside the Alarm class which creates the callback function according to self.Name or self.pin

Comment: So why does the callback need to be created dynamically? And how is Python going to know what the callback is supposed to do? It is straightforward to 'create a function', but there needs to be some way to specify the behaviour of the function. At the moment it sounds like you are asking for Python to magically know that the callback for this event should do a screenshot, while the callback for that event should send an email.

Comment: Ok maybe my word choice is misleading, let me clarify:
Currently I need to add a callback function for each component, which contains code fo what will happen when said component triggers.
I find that very disturbing, since I want to simplify the process as good as possible and the code doesn't get more readable when I have x lines of code per callback. Instead I want ONE callback function which reacts differently, according to which component triggered. Then I only need component callback function that point to said function with the correct parameters.

Comment: I think you need to show some example code of how you would like it to look. At the moment you say it should look like `pir.addEvent('Up', pir.callback, 500)`. Given that you have `pir_callback` defined already (you must do, to have the behaviour defined), just calling `pir.addEvent('Up', pir_callback, 500)` should work fine, no?

Comment: I've edited the original post and pasted the code I have currently. It looks really rough and my approach isn't really my ideal but I couldn't think of any other way to get it working.
Now I only need to "Debounce" once inside the Alarm.callback function, which then points to the correct callback function.
But I'm still not satisfied with how it looks. I was wondering if there's a way to add variable names together? sort of like return self.Name + callback, so if triggered by PIR it returns PIRcallback? Then I could save myself the if - elif - if comparison, which is messy..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, functions are first-class variables themselves, and can be passed around like any other variable. In this case, you should simply pass the callback function directly to your `Alarm` constructor, rather than the name:

```
class Alarm:
    def __init__(self, IO, pin, callback):
        self.IO = IO
        self.pin = pin
        self.callback_func = callback
        if (IO == 'input'):
            GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
        elif (IO == 'output'):
            GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.OUT)
        else:
            print ('Error: No input/output declared')
        self.addEvent('Up', self.callback, 500)

    [...]

    def callback(self):
        global time_stamp
        time_now = time.time()
        if (time_now - time_stamp) >= 0.3:
            time_stamp = time_now
            return self.callback_func()  # <- Don't forget the parentheses here


#Testing Class Init    
REED = Alarm('input', 37, REEDcallback)
PIR = Alarm('input', 36, PIRcallback)
VIBR = Alarm('input', 38, VIBRcallback)
# This bit is now done in the constructor:
# VIBR.addEvent('Up', VIBR.callback, 500)
# PIR.addEvent('Up', PIR.callback, 500)
# REED.addEvent('Up', REED.callback, 500)
```

Comment: I guess sometimes the answer can be simply out of my view. That should do the trick and yes, I've gotta fix that debounce. 
I'll post the solution I came up with now thanks to your answer,

Comment: Okay, running into quite some trouble again.
I don't know how I can run the callback function from with the callback method without it being called upon initialization. I was a little to hasty there thinking I've got a solution.
when giving the function REEDcallback as a parameter it is already called and the callback method is never used. Well, it is used, but only once at the end.... I'm honestly confused.

Comment: Based on the updated code you have pasted into the question, I would say you need to put parentheses after `self.callback_func`, i.e., `self.callback_func()`. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Updated Code again.
Putting in Parantheses didn't fix the other Problem.
The callback Functions (REEDcallback, PIRcallback, VIBRcallback) get triggered by the Initialization of Alarm, i.e., `Alarm('input', 36, 'PIR', **PIRcallback**)`... So instead of the alarm triggering once, I get like up to 10 triggers and THEN the trigger from the callback method.

Comment: Okay.. Some fixing in my IDE later. (I'm using Spyder3 and for some reason it didn't "run" the rewritten code but some old example, so I kept getting buggy output)
Nevertheless I'm now having troubles. I've figured out, I need to use parantheses for **self.cb** as well, so the line is `GPIO.add_event_detect(self.pin, UpDown, callback=self.cb(), bouncetime=btime)`
This now throws the Error:
TypeError: Parameter must be callable
Without the parantheses it works, but doesn't trigger anything.

Comment: No, don't put the parentheses on `self.cb`. With parentheses there, `self.cb` will be called immediately when the `Alarm` instance is being created, which will most likely be less than 400ms since `time_stamp` was set, so it will return `None`, which is not going to set up your callback correctly.

Comment: Yea, I've figured out why it spams. I assumed GPIO.cleanup also cleans any Interrupt Event Detections, but it didn't so I added said cleaning in my Program Termination and it stopped spamming.
`GPIO.add_event_detect(self.pin, UpDown, self.callback_func, bouncetime=btime)`
This works. It also debounces with the inbuilt Debouncer (I'm giving 500ms with the addEvent) which was quite surprising... I still can't use a method inside the Alarm class as callback function, but I've found more threads that cover this issue, so you can consider this resolved. Thx for your help!